# Excel; trying to find events in a column across multiple sheets

Tags: vba, events

I have over 100 worksheets that are identical. I am trying to make 1 new sheet where it scans the other sheets. The scan is for 1 column (H) and to find an event (both >.05 and <-.05). Then I need it to copy the entire row and place it into the new worksheet.

Comment: Can you tell us what you have tried so far?

Comment: {=IFERROR(Index(acw:asti!$A$2:$Q$1270, Small(if(acw:asti!$H$2:$H$1259 > 5%, Row(acw:asti!$H$2:$H$1259)-Row(acw:asti!$H$2+1), Rows (A$2:A2)), Match (A$1, acw:asti!$A$1:$Q$1, 0)),""))}

Comment: I still cant get it to work

Answer (score 0):

Ok I haven't touched VBA in years, but I could quickly come up with this by googling the different steps needed to be achieved. I used random data ranging from cell A1 to H30 usin a few example sheets; You'll obviously need to adapt the code for your needs, but it should be more than enough to get you started!

```
Sub LookForValuesInH()

    Dim WS_Count As Integer
    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    ws.Name = "Results"

    For i = 1 To WS_Count
        Dim Row_Count As Integer
        Row_Count = 30
        For r = 1 To Row_Count
            Worksheets(1).Select
            If Cells(r, 8) >.05 Then
                Worksheets(1).Rows(r).Copy
                ws.Activate
                ws.Paste
                ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
            End If
        Next r
    Next i
End Sub
```